Problem with forked edges in atypical forest.sty
Most examples of output from forest (not unnaturally) follow a pyramidal shape commonly encountered in linguistic trees. As an experiment in culinary recipe formatting, I've tried to invert the pyramid:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,tikz}% xparse for u{<...>}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\newlength{\recitemwd}
\setlength{\recitemwd}{1.3in}
\newcounter{stepnum}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ingreds}{ >{\SplitList{;}}m }{\ProcessList{#1}{\fooaux}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\fooaux}{ m } {\expandafter\fooauxa#1|}
%% #1*=\hrulefill?; #2=?; #3=ingredient
\NewDocumentCommand{\fooauxa}{s o u{|}}{% 
    \hangindent1em\strut#3\strut\par
    \IfBooleanT{#1}{%
        \nointerlineskip
        \vskip1pt
        \textcolor{red}{\hrulefill\enskip}%
        \par
        \nointerlineskip
        \vskip1pt
    }%
}

\def\ingfill{fill=yellow!80!orange!15}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mking}{m}{%
    \parbox{\recitemwd}{\pretolerance10000\bfseries\ingreds{#1}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mkmth}{+m}{%
    \begin{minipage}{\recitemwd}
        \parskip1ex#1
    \end{minipage}
}

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\small

\begin{forest}{for tree={grow'=90,edge={semithick,<-},
%       forked edges, 
        node options={draw,text width=1.25in,rounded corners=1.5pt}}}
    [\mkmth{Bake in a hot waffle iron}
        [\mkmth{Fold beaten egg whites into flour/egg yolk mixture.}
            [\mkmth{Mix together flour, BP and salt.\endgraf Add milk, butter and yolks, mix until smooth}
                [\mking{2 cups flour;2 teaspoons BP;*¼ teaspoon salt;2 cups milk;
                    4 tablespoons butter, melted;4 egg yolks},\ingfill]
            ]
            [\mkmth{Beat egg whites and salt until foamy.\endgraf
                Continuing to beat, add sugar gradually to stiff peaks.}
                [\mking{4 egg whites;*1 pinch salt;2 tablespoons sugar},\ingfill]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}

This works, but, clearly, there are some aspects of the setup that I'm overlooking: When forked edges is uncommented, this is the result;

I realize that this may not be the best use-case for forest and I am certainly not an expert. Still, I like the bracket syntax and would like to continue with this if possible.
What do I need to fix?

Made change to title. Good point.

thanks for editing the title. if neither answer is satisfactory, could you clarify what you are looking for?

You do not need to group the preamble of the tree. If anything, you don't want to do this.
The simplest solution is to move forked edges outside for tree, since it already includes its own for tree.
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{xparse,tikz}% xparse for u{<...>}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\newlength{\recitemwd}
\setlength{\recitemwd}{1.3in}
\newcounter{stepnum}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ingreds}{ >{\SplitList{;}}m }{\ProcessList{#1}{\fooaux}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\fooaux}{ m } {\expandafter\fooauxa#1|}
%% #1*=\hrulefill?; #2=?; #3=ingredient
\NewDocumentCommand{\fooauxa}{s o u{|}}{% 
  \hangindent1em\strut#3\strut\par
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{%
    \nointerlineskip
    \vskip1pt
    \textcolor{red}{\hrulefill\enskip}%
    \par
    \nointerlineskip
    \vskip1pt
  }%
}

\def\ingfill{fill=yellow!80!orange!15}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mking}{m}{%
  \parbox{\recitemwd}{\pretolerance10000\bfseries\ingreds{#1}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mkmth}{+m}{%
  \begin{minipage}{\recitemwd}
    \parskip1ex#1
  \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}

\small

\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={grow'=90,edge={semithick,<-},
    node options={draw,text width=1.25in,rounded corners=1.5pt}}
  [\mkmth{Bake in a hot waffle iron}
      [\mkmth{Fold beaten egg whites into flour/egg yolk mixture.}
          [\mkmth{Mix together flour, BP and salt.\endgraf Add milk, butter and yolks, mix until smooth}
              [\mking{2 cups flour;2 teaspoons BP;*¼ teaspoon salt;2 cups milk;
                  4 tablespoons butter, melted;4 egg yolks},\ingfill]
          ]
          [\mkmth{Beat egg whites and salt until foamy.\endgraf
              Continuing to beat, add sugar gradually to stiff peaks.}
              [\mking{4 egg whites;*1 pinch salt;2 tablespoons sugar},\ingfill]
          ]
      ]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}


EDIT
Note that your code produces copious bad boxes because you are putting larger things into smaller things. (text width is too small for the width of minipages you use.)
Moreover, you are somewhat reinventing the wheel. forest itself makes nodes into tabulars if you use align and can itself split content etc.
More generally, it is generally easier to use pgf/forest styles than to insert custom macros such as \imgfill. Although that works here, it tends to fail if things get even a little more complicated.
I am not convinced I'd use forest for recipes. (At least, it isn't what I use when typesetting recipes.) But, if I were to adopt your approach, I'd consider something like this:
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/716550/ addaswyd o gwestiwn sgmoye: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/716537/
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\newlength{\recitemwd}
\setlength{\recitemwd}{1.3in}

\forestset{%
  recipe/.style={%
    forked edges,
    for tree={%
      grow'=90,
      edge={semithick,<-},
      draw,
      rounded corners=1.5pt,
      inner xsep=2pt,
      inner ysep=0pt,
    },
    /utils/exec={\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}},
  },
  mkmth/.style={%
      align=R,
  },
  ingfill/.style={fill=yellow!80!orange!15},
  mking/.style={%
    font=\bfseries,
    align=H,
    before typesetting nodes={%
      temptoksa={},
      split option={content}{;}{temptoksa,mking aux}, 
      content/.register=temptoksa,
    },
  },
  mking aux/.style={%
    temptoksc=,
    temptoksb=,
    split={#1}{*}{temptoksc,temptoksb},
    if temptoksc={}{%
      temptoksa+={\\\cmidrule(lr){1-1}},
      temptoksa+/.register=temptoksb,
    }{%
      temptoksa+={\\[-1ex]},
      temptoksa+/.register=temptoksc,
    },
  },
}
\newcolumntype{R}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\recitemwd}@{}}
\newcolumntype{H}{@{}>{\raggedright\hangindent1em\arraybackslash}p{\recitemwd}@{}}

\begin{document}

\small

\begin{forest}
  recipe,
  [Bake in a hot waffle iron,mkmth
    [Fold beaten egg whites into flour/egg yolk mixture.,mkmth
      [{Mix together flour, BP and salt.}\\{Add milk, butter and yolks, mix until smooth},mkmth
        [{2 cups flour;2 teaspoons BP;*¼ teaspoon salt;2 cups milk;
          4 tablespoons butter, melted;4 egg yolks},mking,ingfill]
      ]
      [Beat egg whites and salt until foamy.\\
        {Continuing to beat, add sugar gradually to stiff peaks.},mkmth
        [4 egg whites;*1 pinch salt;2 tablespoons sugar,mking,ingfill]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}

Explanation:

recipe is the basic forest style;
array is used so we can define a couple of custom column specifications for tabular, both of which create minipages of width \recipemwd;
imgfill is a style to produce the fill used for some nodes;
mking is a style for producing an ingredients listing:

use ; to separate lines and ;* when a rule is desired;


mkmth is a style for producing instructions:

use \\ to separate lines;


where a comma occurs in the content, braces (curly brackets) are required, but these are not otherwise necessary.

The list of ingredients is split twice:

at any ;:


the first item is stored in a forest toks register
any further items are processed further;


at any *:


if the first item is empty, a rule is added to the toks register after the \\ and the second item is then added
otherwise, a \\ is added followed by the first item.

The effect of this is to split and reconstitute the contents of the node, substituting row breaks for each semicolon and adding a rule if this is immediately followed by an asterisk.
Apologies for the lack of a second image. A bug in the latest Okular-on-X means my images are useless. Many thanks to egreg for providing the first one.

Thank you. Very interesting, and a lot to think about here. The manual says (page 37) "[align=…]Creates a left/center/right-aligned multiline node, or a tabular node." (Emphasis added] I'm not clear: what triggers the creation of a tabular node?

@sgmoye It's always tabular. If you say align=center, it is equivalent to align=c which makes a tabular with a single c type column. Similarly for left and right. So you can put any valid column spec as the argument to align and that's all there is to it.

As suggested here, use forked edge instead of forked edges.
...
\begin{forest}{for tree={grow'=90,edge={semithick,<-},
      forked edge,                                   % <---- changed here
        node options={draw,text width=1.25in,rounded corners=1.5pt}}}
    [\mkmth{Bake in a hot waffle iron}
        [\mkmth{Fold beaten egg whites into flour/egg yolk mixture.}
            [\mkmth{Mix together flour, BP and salt.\endgraf Add milk, butter and yolks, mix until smooth}
                [\mking{2 cups flour;2 teaspoons BP;*¼ teaspoon salt;2 cups milk;
                    4 tablespoons butter, melted;4 egg yolks},\ingfill]
            ]
            [\mkmth{Beat egg whites and salt until foamy.\endgraf
                Continuing to beat, add sugar gradually to stiff peaks.}
                [\mking{4 egg whites;*1 pinch salt;2 tablespoons sugar},\ingfill]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
...


